# How handle HTTP Request taht produces XML document inside the body of HTTP Response in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

in this time I am studying the Spring MVC showcase example downlodable from the STS dashboard

However, the situation is the following one:

In a view named home.jsp I have this two links:

```
        <li>
            <a id="byProducesAcceptXml" class="writeXmlLink" href="<c:url value="/mapping/produces" />">By produces via Accept=appilcation/xml</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="byProducesXmlExt" class="writeXmlLink" href="<c:url value="/mapping/produces.xml" />">By produces via ".xml"</a>
        </li>
```

The first link generate an HTTP Request towards the URL: **/mapping/produces**
The second link generate an HTTP Request towards the URL: **/mapping/produces.xml**

Both this links have **class="writeXmlLink"** and related to the click event of all the links having this class there is the following Jquery function:

```
$("a.writeXmlLink").click(function() {

    var link = $(this);     // Variabile che contiene il riferimento all'elemento nel DOM che ha scatenato l'evento click (il link clickato) 

    // Viene eseguita la chiamata ajax 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: link.attr("href"),                         // Indirizzo verso cui è indirizzata la richiesta 
        beforeSend: function(req) {                     // Prima di inviare l'HTTP Request esegui la funzione passandogli il parametro req 
            if (!this.url.match(/\.xml$/)) {                            // Se l'url termina con .xml 
                req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");      // Aggiunge alla HTTP Request l'header Accept: application/xml 
            }
        },
        success: function(xml) {
            MvcUtil.showSuccessResponse(MvcUtil.xmlencode(xml), link);
        },
        error: function(xhr) { 
            MvcUtil.showErrorResponse(xhr.responseText, link);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This script is quite clear for me...in practice it happens that:

When the first link is clicked the jQuery script start and do the AJAX call, before send the request check if the URL end with .xml and because this link don't end with .xml sends the HTTP Request that is handled in my controller class by the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/produces", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody JavaBean byProducesXml() {
    System.out.println("Dentro byProducesXml()");
    return new JavaBean();
}
```

This method simply create a new JavaBean object and return it within an XML document putting inside the body field of HTTP Response. So the HTTP Response comes to the client (my browser) and the JQuery script call an other function that show the output.

The JavaBean class is a simplice class that contain only two valorised variables and the getter/setter method:

```
@XmlRootElement
```

public class JavaBean {

```
private String foo = "bar";

private String fruit = "apple";
    // GETTER & Setter
```

So the HTTP Response comes to the client (my browser) and the JQuery script call an other function that show the output (that is the XML document inside the body of the HTTP Response)

Infact in this case my output is: **barapple**

Ok...now when the second link is clicked start again the jQuery function that do the AJAX call, before send the request check if the URL end with .xml and because this time the link end with **.xml** the code inside the if body is executed, so it is executed the following operation:

```
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
```

That add an header namend Accept and having value "application/xml" tho the HTTP Request headers.

Now the AJAX call send the HTTP Request that is handled by the same previus controller method that return the same thing to my browser and here appear me the same output message:
**barapple**

Now my doubt is relate to the difference between the two Request that is generated by clicking on the two links.

The first one have not the Accept header setted, the second one have this header setted...the result is the same...what changes? what are the differences between the two requests?

Comment: @AndreaNobill: I think the problem is in the controller. May you change the return value of byProducesXml to String and try again?

Comment: This is not a problem !!! The example is the Spring MVC official showcase project and work well !!! My answer was related to understand well how it work but this example have not working problem !!!